# How to insert view inside listview row item

Tags: android, listview

Am creating a chat conversion screen. i had listview to show messages from and to persons. My challenge is to display some view in between the chat conversion as like below image.[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRU3M.png].

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have xml? pretty simple xml stuff here.

Answer (score -1):

May I see your ListView Adapter class?

Instantiate your layout inside this Override method of your adapter class.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder; //instantiate your view
      View v;
      if(/*your condition*/){
        v =LayoutInflater.from(Context).inflate(R.id.yourlayout,null,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //do your stuffs
   }
 } 

private static class ViewHolder {
//declare your view here..
}
```